# Defining a piecewise multivariate function

Tags: python, function, piecewise

I want to define a function in Python, of variables x (position) and t (time). The function is periodic in time. Each cycle consists of two time intervals, namely t<sub>off</sub> and t<sub>on</sub> in that order. In the first half, i.e. from the beginning of a cycle to t=t<sub>off</sub>, the function is zero. While after that, till t=t<sub>off</sub>+t<sub>on</sub>, the function is a sawtooth function in x.

I tried defining the function in the following way.

```
def F_f(y):
    return 0
def F_n(y):
    return signal.sawtooth(y)
def F(y,t):
    if((t%T)<=t_F):
        return 0
    elif((t%T)>t_F):
        return F_n(y)
```

Now, when I proceed to plot the function against *t*, keeping *x* constant, I get an error that reads,

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I also tried using the piecewise function but that too runs into an error while plotting against *x* whiel keeping *t* constant.

How can I redefine my function to avoid these issues? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The function `F` assumes single values for both inputs, not arrays. If `t` is an array, then `(t%T)<=t_F` is an array of booleans, not a single boolean, thus also the error. You could change the way you use it, e.g. as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import sawtooth

x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
t = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
T = 2
t_F = 1.5

def F_f(x):
    return 0

def F_n(x):
    return sawtooth(x)

def F(x,t):
    if ((t%T)<=t_F):
        return F_f(x)
    elif ((t%T)>t_F):
        return F_n(x)

res = np.full((len(x), len(t)), np.nan)
for i, a in enumerate(x):
    for j, b in enumerate(t):
        res[i, j] = F(a, b)
```

But you can replace

```
def F_f(x):
    return 0
```

by

```
def F_f(x):
    return np.full((len(x),), 0)
```

and then you can use it as you intended:

```
res = np.full((len(x), len(t)), np.nan)
for j, b in enumerate(t):
    res[:, j] = F(x, b)
```